# Harm in exiting Terminal mid update?

Tags: command-line

I trying to get to grips with ubuntu(as a brand new convert). The only commands I am entering into the terminal are things like 'sudo apt-get update' or 'sudo apt-get install build-essential bison flex libsndfile1-dev libasound2-dev libqt4-dev libqscintilla2-dev'.

The installs and updates haven't quite been working as I want(I don't know the causes yet), I just want to know if I can experiment, exit terminal and reinstall things that I have already tried to install without causing problems to the system.

For now I just want to have peace of mind in my trouble shooting, before I need to ask more specific questions about issues.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To some extent. The update/upgrade process and the installing of software, if stopped in the middle, can throw some errors at you but those are solvable.

Example of an error you can see is this one: [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem) with [this as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/102084/15811).

You can also see this as part of the experience. If you break it you can always re-install since you most likely do not have any important personal files it will not be harmful. Or otherwise put those files on a pendrive.

But as a general rule I would advice to always let commands run their course.

Comment: Great, I don't intend to kill commands often, it was just a case of the downloads taking very long to load or even freezing.

Comment: if all you lack is experience you are bound to get some :D

Answer (score 0):

apt-get is fairly robust, and will in most cases survive being interrupted, but It may leave the rest of the system unstable until you either finish the install or roll it back. Other commands have different, well, everything and your mileage will vary. i.e. vim is robust enough to save almost all of your work in progress, but interrupting compiles may introduce subtle errors, which make will try to compensate for.